# How to get Facebook Like Box "Dark Scheme" to work correctly? (Background is transparent.)

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, wordpress, facebook-social-plugins

I have installed the Faceook like and recommend box on my site and choose the dark theme version of the code which is supposed to have a white background. However as you can see in the screen shot the background is white.

The preview version of the code on the Facebook website displays correctly (white background.) I'm assuming something there is some CSS on my site that is overriding the background. (Which is strange since this is an iframe, I don't see how that could happen.)

You can check out what is happening on my [side bar](http://noahsdad.com/), and here's a screen shot. (The background should be white. The same things is happening on the recommend box also. [screen shot http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Screen-Shot-2012-07-10-at-6.46.30-PM.png](http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Screen-Shot-2012-07-10-at-6.46.30-PM.png). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try

```
.fb_iframe_widget {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect! thanks. The only issue now is how to make the links a bit more readable. (if you check ou the page you'll notice some of them are a light gray color, and other are blue.)